# Add annotation after retrieving users latitude and longitude from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mapkit

I am trying to add a mapView annotation of all the online user after retrieving their latitude and longitude from Firebase. I am able to print it as an optional or as a CLLocationDegrees aka Double, but when I try to add it into my user.userAnnotation attribute I get a fatal error. This is what I am printing:

```
this is the users lat Optional(19.435477800000001) 
this is the user latitude in CLLocationDegrees 19.4354778 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

And this is my function:

```
func fetchOnlineUsers() {
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let user = AppUser()
            user.userEmail = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["name"] as? String
            user.latitude = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["latitude"] as? Double
            user.longitude = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["longitude"] as? Double
            user.online = ((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["online"] as? Bool)!
            print("this is the user latitude \(user.latitude)")
            let userLat = CLLocationDegrees(user.latitude!)
            let userLon = CLLocationDegrees(user.longitude!)  

            if user.online == true {
                user.userAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLat, longitude: userLon)

                self.users.append(user)
            }
            print("this are the users \(self.users)")
            print("this is the dictionary \(dictionary)")

            self.mainMapView.addAnnotations([user.userAnnotation])
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well some of the value/s that you´re getting is `nil`. Try this instead:

```
guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject],
let email = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["name"] as? String,
let latitude = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["latitude"] as? Double,
let longitude = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["longitude"] as? Double,
let online = ((snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["online"] as? Bool)! else { // Some error }
```

If this succeeds you can start use the variables created in the `guard let` and they will 1: have a value, 2: not be Optional.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with some missing code. I think your answer can still work. I will check now.

Comment: @cosmos, check if the answer helps you otherwise do tell me.

Comment: Well if you hit the `else` then you have a problem with some value. You could either return/continue in there or make a check of which value that fails.

Comment: Ok, so now im getting an error in let online = ...   It says initializer for conditional binding must have optional type not Bool

Comment: Does it return true/false or 0/1?

Comment: I send it as a string to firebase and then when I retrieve it returns 0/1 for some reason.

Comment: Pass it `as? String` then and then convert it afterwards.

Comment: I was able to print this: ["latitude": 19.4354778, "online": 1, "longitude": -99.1364789]
Optional(19.435477800000001) ---- It still comes as an optional. -- This are my print lines : print(dictionary)
            print(driver.latitude)

Comment: Are you printing the latitude and longitude variables? I yes use ! because they have a value after the guard.