# Taking latitude & longitude from Cloud Firestore and adding them to Mapbox as annotation

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mapbox

I'm trying to retrieve the flight number, latitude & longitude from all Firestore documents and add them as Mapbox annotations to a mapView. So far the code pulls the data from Cloud Firestore and stores them as variables. Aditionally the code displays a Mapbox map with coordinates but they must be assigned manually in the array

Im having trouble with appending the variables from Firestore to the coordinates array.

I found this ["Add annotation after retrieving users latitude and longitude from Firebase"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39733874/add-annotation-after-retrieving-users-latitude-and-longitude-from-firebase) which was along the correct lines but its to do with firebase and not firestore.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    mapView.styleURL = MGLStyle.darkStyleURL
    mapView.tintColor = .lightGray
    mapView.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 66)
    mapView.zoomLevel = 2
    mapView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(mapView)

    var aircraftArray = [""]


    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let AircraftRef = db.collection("LiveAircraftData").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let FlightNumber = document.documentID
                let latitude = document.get("Latitude") as! Double
                let longitude = document.get("Longitude") as! Double

                print(FlightNumber, latitude, longitude)

                var Coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                aircraftArray.append(Coordinates)

                var pointAnnotations = [MGLPointAnnotation]()
                for coordinate in Coordinates {
                    let point = MGLPointAnnotation()
                    point.coordinate = coordinate
                    point.title = "\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)"
                    pointAnnotations.append(point)
                }

                mapView.addAnnotations(pointAnnotations)


            }

        }
    }
}
```

[This is what my database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui8ZO.png)

[screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT30X.png)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the issue is. As it sits, you're iterating over the documents from Firestore getting the flight number, long and lat and printing them to the console. That's where you would add them to the coordinates array. However, that array appears to be defined after the loop so.... what's the plan there?

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the comment. I've added the array back into the loop. The issue I was having was with appending the `CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)`. It won't allow me to add the latitude and longitude to the array. I think i'm missing the correct syntax or something.

Comment: Can you update your question with current code? Also, please don't include links in questions as they break and change and that invalidates the question. If you need to use an image, embed it in the question.

Comment: Also `var myCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)` and then add myCoordinate to your array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've updated the code but now its complaining about `Cannot convert value of type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' to expected argument type 'String'` and `Type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'`. Have I got the data types wrong?

Comment: lol. You've defined your aircraftArray as an array of strings! `var aircraftArray = [""]` just change that to store a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` type.

Comment: I'm such an idiot ahaha

Comment: Sorry to keep pestering but do you know how to ammend the error `Type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'`?

Comment: Its something to do with the `for Coordinates in Coordinates`

Comment: Sure. You can't do `for coordinate in Coordinates {` as Coordinates is not an array (sequence), it's a single var defined as `var Coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(lati`. You can only loop over sequences like a for..loop. Not point in iterating over a single var.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I think i've sorted it.